# Operation timed out Splunk + Python

Tags: python-2.7, splunk

I have install Splunk Python SDK 
and i am trying to connect to splunk cloud 
and give me this error

socket.error: [Errno 60] Operation timed out

this my code

```
import splunklib.client as client


class SplunkSearch():
    def __init__(self):

        self.service = client.connect(
                    host=Config.DEVELOPMENT_CONF['splunk']['host'],
                    port=Config.DEVELOPMENT_CONF['splunk']['port'],
                    username=Config.DEVELOPMENT_CONF['splunk']['username'],
                    password=Config.DEVELOPMENT_CONF['splunk']['password'],timeout=None)
```

Comment: What's your port? 443? `•For Splunk cloud user, the host name is something like http-inputs-xx.splunkcloud.com or http-inputs-xx.cloud.splunk.com, port is 443`

Answer (score 1):

Please check what is host name in your configuration file. I guess you must use https://hostname:8089. This will resolve your issue.